# prevent matlab function from displaying output

Tags: matlab

I don't know why Matlab doesn't do this, but if no output arguments are assigned for a function, I would prefer my functions not to output to the console.

E.g.

```
function out=getmagic(n)
    out=magic(n);
    figure; 
    plot(out(1,:));
end
```

For high numbers this is increasingly more annoying if you forget the `;` mark at the end of the line when calling the function. My solution so far is to include an `if`statement at the end of the function:

```
if nargin==0 %no output argument is requested
    out=[]; %shorten ouput argument to prevent flooding of console
end
```

is there any better way of doing this (e.g. wouldn't give any output at all)?

Comment: To prevent flooding the console, put a `;` in the end of your function call...  If you forgot to put the `;` that is a coding error. MATLAB doesn't fix your code according to your intentions. Just go and fix your code. Also, you meant `nargout`?

Comment: It's a design choice by MathWorks I would like to change and others may also dislike. The question is how to adjust this design, not whether it complies with existing design choices, otherwisely stated: the answer I'm looking for is not _just comply with existing design choices_.

Comment: Its part of the language.... If you don't like it, use python, or C. It is possible that there is a solution, but that would just be encouraging bad MATLAB code design

Comment: I get that part. But there are ways around it in this case, and people who know how. It seems legit to ask for knowledge about that here..

Comment: That can also be a good question when you need to release a function that is idiot-proof. I sometimes have the impression that guys here are mostly sole researchers or at least doesn't develop tools for users, so they tend to stick the "right principle theorm" but with no regard to front-end considerations

Comment: @Adiel sorry, I don't understand, can you elaborate a bit more in laymans terms?

Comment: Your question can be one that a developer ask himself when he build a function that designed to be used by others, so you can't promise that they will use `;` when they run it, but you also don't want to spam their command window. It's not a good example because external users usually doesn't work from command window, but there is some ignorance here from that aspect of programming ("acrobatic" code vs readable one, for example). Researchers widely use matlab, and they usually write code for themselves only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would typically do something like this:

```
function varargout = getmagic(n)

    out=magic(n);
    figure; 
    plot(out(1,:));

    if nargout>0
        varargout{1} = out;
    end

end
```

Now if you call it with an output argument you'll get the value of `out`; but if you call it with no output argument, you'll get nothing at all.

Comment: Yes, but still just write a `;` instead, if the only problem is just that the function writes on console.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Sure, but if you do this then you don’t need to worry about the `;`.